# How to use Cramers rule in Mathematica

Tags: matrix

How do I use Mathematica to use Cramer's rule for the following equations?

"-2x1+ 3x3 = 12" "x2 - 3x4 = 0" "2x1 + 3x2 - 2x3 = 0" "-3x3 + 2x4 = -15"

*the number after the x's are subscripts*

Comment: The only reason to use Cramer's Rule in Mathematica is because a homework exercise asks you to.  Use `LinearSolve[A, b]` to solve `A.x == b` -- see the documentation for examples in code.

Comment: I've tried this but still can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cramers rule requests that the equation are expressed in matrix form: m.x==b. Then the solution vector x={x1,x2..} is given by:

```
xi = Det[mi] / Det[m]
```

where mi is the matrix m with the i-th column replaced by b.

Therefore with m0 and b:

```
m0 = {{-2, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 1, 0, -3}, {2, 3, -2, 0}, {0, 0, -3, 2}};
b = {12, 0, 0, -15};
```

we can apply Cramers rule (we take the transpose because it is easier to replace the column)

```
Table[m = Transpose@m0; m[[i]] = b; Det[m]/Det[m0], {i, 4}]
```

[image]

We can verify this by using "LinearSolve":

```
LinearSolve[m0, b]
```

[image]